# $a_n$ is relatively prime to $a_k$ for $k<n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Let the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ be defined by $a_n=|n(n+1)-19|$. Show that for $n\neq 4$, if $a_n$ is relatively prime to $a_k$ for all $k<n$, then $a_n$ is prime.

The first few terms are $19, 17,13,7,1,11,23,37,53,71,91$, where $a_{10}=91$ is the first non-prime term (other than $a_4=1$), and indeed it is not relatively prime to $a_2=13$ and $a_3=7$.

Comment: **Hint** $\,\ 7\mid a(10)\,\Rightarrow\, 7\mid a(3)\ $ by $\,10\equiv 3\pmod 7\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $n>4$ and $a_n$ is composite. Let $p$ be the smallest prime dividing $a_n$, so
$$
  p^2\leq a_n=n(n+1)-19\leq 4n^2.
$$
Hence $p\leq 2n$. Let
$$
  k=\begin{cases}
    n-p&\text{if }n\geq p,\\
    p-1-n&\text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$
Then $k<n$ and $k(k+1)\equiv n(n+1)\equiv19$ mod $p$. Thus $p|a_k$, so $\gcd(a_k,a_n)\geq p>1$.

Answer (score 1):

$n\ge 4\Rightarrow 0<\overbrace{n^2\!+\!n\!-\!19}^{\large a(n)\ :=\ a_{\Large n}} \color{#c00}{< (n\!+\!1)^2}\,$  so a composite $\,a(n)\,$ has a proper factor $\,d\color{#c00}{\le n},\,$ thus $\,d\mid a(n\!-\!d)\,$ too, $ $ by $\ a(n\!-\!d)\equiv a(n)\equiv 0\,\pmod{\! d},\:$ by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)